# Taking screenshot of MEmu

Tags: c#, bitmap, screenshot

I downloaded a class with handy methods that I use to take screenshots of other programs for a while now

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace EmulatorObserver.model
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Provides functions to capture the entire screen, or a particular window, and save it to a file.
    /// </summary>
    public static class ScreenCapture
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     Creates an Image object containing a screen shot of a specific window
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="handle">The handle to the window. (In windows forms, this is obtained by the Handle property)</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Bitmap CaptureWindow(IntPtr handle)
        {
            // get te hDC of the target window
            IntPtr hdcSrc = GetWindowDC(handle);
            // get the size
            RECT windowRect = new RECT();
            GetWindowRect(handle, ref windowRect);
            int width = windowRect.right - windowRect.left;
            int height = windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top;
            // create a device context we can copy to
            IntPtr hdcDest = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcSrc);
            // create a bitmap we can copy it to,
            // using GetDeviceCaps to get the width/height
            IntPtr hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcSrc, width, height);
            // select the bitmap object
            IntPtr hOld = SelectObject(hdcDest, hBitmap);
            // bitblt over
            BitBlt(hdcDest, 0, 0, width, height, hdcSrc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
            // restore selection
            SelectObject(hdcDest, hOld);
            // clean up 
            DeleteDC(hdcDest);
            ReleaseDC(handle, hdcSrc);

            // get a .NET image object for it
            Bitmap raw;
            using(Image img = Image.FromHbitmap(hBitmap))
            {
                raw = (Bitmap)img.Clone();
            }

            // free up the Bitmap object
            DeleteObject(hBitmap);

            return raw;
        }

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Win32 API
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct RECT
        {
            public int left;
            public int top;
            public int right;
            public int bottom;
        }

        public const int SRCCOPY = 0x00CC0020;                                                      // BitBlt dwRop parameter

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT rect);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern bool BitBlt(IntPtr hObject, int nXDest, int nYDest, int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hObjectSource, int nXSrc, int nYSrc, int dwRop);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern bool DeleteDC(IntPtr hDC);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hDC, IntPtr hObject);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleBitmap(IntPtr hDC, int nWidth, int nHeight);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr hDC);

    }
}
```

so far it worked nicely, but when trying to take a screenshot of an Android emulator MEmu

[image: MEmu de facto view]

the resulting picture looks like this

[image: MEmu buggy view]

what can I not take a screenshot of the content by running 'ScreenCapture.CaptureWindow(h).Save(@"screenshot.bmp");' ? what way do I have to (quickly) get these pictures?